# 4 cycles in a cubic planar bipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory

I am trying to get (upper and lower) bounds on the number of 4-cycles($K_{2,2}$) in planar 3-regular bipartite graphs. The best I have been able to get is a bound based on the Euler characteristic. I know the upper bounds should be better than for general bipartite graphs due to the utility graph being a forbidden minor. The planarity and 3-regularity seem to also impose a lower bound.

For a graph as above with $2n$ vertices and $3n$ edges, I have gotten so far that there must be at least $\frac{n}{2}+4$ square faces in the graph by using the Euler characteristic. Are there such graphs where the faces are the only 4-cycles? It seems like a better bound should be possible.

Also I have come up with a construction for a planar bipartite graph (not cubic) that has at least $4n+2$ four-cycles. But since it isn't cubic, and I am not sure if it is tight anyway, I don't see how it helps me.

If there are known results, those would be welcome, but I would really like to learn how to prove the bounds for this on my own. With that in mind even hints are acceptable.

**EDIT**

Okay, I think there are some fishy numbers in the comments, so I am going to show my work. We are assuming connected graphs.

Three regular graphs have an even number of vertices, and every bipartite cubic graph has a Tait coloring of the edges. This implies for a graph on $2n$ vertices, there are precisely $n$ in each side of the bipartition. By the handshaking lemma, there are $3n$ edges. Thus, Euler's characteristic implies that there are precisely $n+2$ faces, none of which are triangles. This should imply based on dtldarek's comment, that there are at most $n+2$ 4-cycles. But that can't be true (that for triangle free planar graphs all 4-cycles are faces), because of the following bipartite planar graph:

[image: counterexample]

It has 4 faces, but 5 distinct four-cycles.

I will post my lower bound derivation when I get a chance.

Comment: The cube is a planar cubic graph that has $2\cdot 4$ vertices, $3\cdot 4$ edges and $4/2+4$ square faces (each face is a square).

Comment: I'm only saying that any bounds have to admit that example. On the other hand, the cube seems _saturated_ with squares, i.e. it should be easy to construct a graph with smaller number of squares per vertex (e.g. [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_octahedron)). I'm not sure I follow which bounds you call lower and which upper.

Comment: @dtldarek yes sorry, correct. I will fix it. By lower bound I mean the minimum number of cycles possible and by upper bound I mean the maximum number of cycles. both parameterized by half the number of vertices .

Comment: @dtldarek Now you have me wondering where I made a mistake. Would it help if I posted my derivation?

Comment: @dtldarek okay. I only reversed the inequality sign then probably. I will look over my work again.

Comment: As for the lower bound, the [fullerenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fullerene) provide examples of $0$, the problem is those are not exactly to your specifications (e.g. infinite or not-bipartite). But it is a start ;-)

Comment: @dtldarek I wasn't sure where you were getting your numbers from in your second to last comment, so I posted my work which shows completely different numbers. Also unless I made a mistake(very possible), I have reason to believe that if we restrict them to bipartite cubic planar, there is at the very least a constant lower bound on the number of 4 cycles (the number I calculated was 6).

Comment: That comment was clearly wrong, I confused the parameter $n$, the number vertices $2n$, and it all got mixed up in the formulas. Moreover it coincided with what you have written and so my rambling followed. Yet, consider [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_cuboctahedron), it has $48$ vertices and $12$ squares, which in your notation gives $n=24$, and $12 < \frac{24}{2}+4$

Comment: @dtldarek also I have a counterexample to the faces/cycles correspondence you implied. I am trying to find a pic of the graph since it is small.

Comment: I also got a lower bound of 6 and there are at least 3 graphs with such a number of squares.

Comment: Of course, a few cases do not mean much. BTW, your example is not cubic.

Comment: @dtldarek Doesn't matter because the claim it is refuting is about planar triangle free graphs. Or did I misunderstand? Do only cubic graphs have that property?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, please share the expanded example (I recommend [inkscape](http://inkscape.org) for drawing).

Comment: @dtldarek I realized the expanded example was also subcubic, so I deleted that from my comment. It sounded like the claim you made was that if triangle free planar graphs contain any 4-cycles, they are faces. That graph is a counterexample. A planar triangle free graph that has more 4 cycles than square faces.

Comment: Well, if you would aim for non-cubic then why don't take $K_{n,2}$? It has $\Theta(n^2)$ squares. As for the cubic graphs, my intuition was that even if a 4-cycle was not a face, then inside it you would have to have a non-square face too, so it wouldn't matter much. BTW, There are infinitely many such graphs with just 6 squares.

Comment: @dtldarek okay, my point was only that your intuition was wrong, because my definition of "doesn't matter much" is that they don't exist. The graph was only to prove that point, the fact that it isn't cubic doesn't matter, unless you can prove that it does actually matter. Pretty much any time there are two squares that share two edges there will be a 4-cycle that is not a face. Okay, can you let me know how to construct an infinite family of cubic bipartite planar graphs with exactly 6 four-cycles? Since my question is about _proving_ the bounds, that would be relevant.

Comment: The 3-regularity _is_ important. I will phrase it differently: if two squares share two edges, then the vertex in the middle of the shared edge needs one more edge, and handling that will create more faces than squares. As for the infinite family, create a tube (arbitrary length) of hexagons of circumference 3 (hexagons), so that on each end you will have a hexagon with 3 vertices of degree 2 and then connect those into a new vertex (thus creating 3 squares on each side).

Comment: @dtldarek okay fair enough. That wasn't clear to me from your original post that that is what you meant. I found a gadget for adding single edges to subcubic graphs. I will take a look at that and see how it affects the graph. Thanks for the hexagon construction. I will look at the base case when I get a chance. It is a bit disappointing that the easy bounds are tight. I was hoping for something more interesting.

Comment: Actually I can't find a infinite family of graphs for the upper bound. Surely there are examples for $n$ but I didn't manage to get $n+2$ besides the cube.

Comment: @dtldarek I am still looking for a way to prove the face thing formally. It appears that if I assume it is three-vertex-connected then a square that shares two edges with another will induce the utility-graph in a cubic bipartite graph. So any counter example cannot be polyhedral.

Comment: Sadly, any approach I have tried would immediately become a horrible caseology. As I use math.se mostly for fun (a multitude of convoluted cases is just not fun), and have my own research problems to do, I'm not willing to spare more time on this one, sorry. Should you arrive on some solution, I'd love to hear about it, but I can't help you more. Good luck on your endeavor!

Comment: @dtldarek I understand completely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's look at [bicubic](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BicubicGraph.html) planar graphs. As you say, there must be $2n$ vertices, $3n$ edges, and $n+2$ faces for some $n$. Suppose there are $F_j$ faces of length $j$; then we want lower and upper bounds on $F_4$ in terms of $n$.

Note that every 4-cycle in the graph must be a face in the planar embedding, because any chord in the 4-cycle would give you cycles of length 3, impossible in a bipartite graph. The graph you have at the end of the question is not a counterexample because it is not cubic (in a 3-regular graph, there would be two triangles on the bottom.)

### Upper bound

The upper bound is $n+2$. This is obviously the maximum possible because it is the total number of faces, and it is achieved by the cube graph, where $n = 4$.

[image]

This is the only graph that achieves the bound, because it is the only cubic planar graph consisting only of squares. If all the faces are squares, then 4 times the number of faces must be 3 times the number of vertices, or
$$ 4(n+2) = 6n $$
so $n = 4$.

If we exclude this single graph, then the upper bound is $n$, and graphs with $F_4 = n$ can be found for arbitrarily large $n$ (see the prism graph at the end of this answer.)

To prove this, we need to show that we cannot have $n + 1$ 4-sided faces and a single $j$-sided face, with $j > 4$.
In this case
$$
6n = 4F_4 + jF_j = 4(n+1) + j
$$
so $j = 2n - 4$. The same logic as [this answer by Henning Makholm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/541692/59435) applies:

> Now start by drawing the face with $2n - 4$ sides. That uses up $2n -4$ nodes. Since the graph is cubic, each of these nodes have an extra neighbor. But if those neighbors are all different, then there would be at least $4n - 8$ nodes in the graph which is too many.
>
> Therefore, there must be a pair of corners of the $j$-gon that share a neighbor outside the $j$-gon. Since [all other faces are 4-cycles], this is only possible if these two nodes are separated by one corner in the $j$-gon. But then it's impossible for the extra leg of the corner between them to connect to anything, which is absurd. So the graph cannot exist.

(It's not *that* absurd to have an edge going to another graph component 
contained within a face, but such an edge would be a cut-edge, which cannot exist in a regular bipartite graph.)

### Lower bound

The lower bound is an arbitrarily small multiple of $n$. We can see this by applying a [bitruncation operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitruncation), which replaces every vertex by a hexagon and leaves a smaller version of each face (with the same number of sides). Thus, starting from the cube, we get a bitruncated cube (aka [truncated octahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_octahedron)) with 6 squares and 8 hexagons ($n = 12$).

[image]

Bitruncating that gives a polyhedron with 6 squares and 32 hexagons ($n = 36$).

[image]

Bitruncating that gives a polyhedron with 6 squares and 104 hexagons ($n = 108$).

[image]

Here are the corresponding planar graphs:
[image]
[image]
[image]

In general, bitruncating yields a graph with 3 times as many vertices and the same number of squares, so we can keep going and get $F_4$ to be less than $\epsilon n$ for any $\epsilon > 0$.

Another option would be a [chamfering operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chamfer_(geometry)), which replaces every edge by a hexagon and every face by a smaller face of the same number of sides. Starting from the cube, this gives you 4 times as many vertices with each step, so $n$ grows even faster, while always keeping 6 squares.

### Absolute bounds

As you mention, any 3-regular planar bipartite graph must have at least 6 squares (assuming you forbid digons, that is, two edges between the same vertices). One way to show this is that 3 times the number of vertices equals the sum of each face's length, so

$$\begin{align}
6n &= 4F_4 + 6F_6 + 8F_8 + \ldots \\
&\geq 4F_4 + 6(n+2-F_4) \\
&= 6n + 12 - 2F_4 \\
2F_4 &\geq 12 \\
F_4 &\geq 6.
\end{align}$$

(If you allow digons, you can get this guy with two squares: [image: a graph with four vertices, two squares, and two digons])

There is no absolute upper bound on $F_4$ (independent of $n$), since you can have prism graphs with arbitrarily many squares:

[image]

These all have $F_4 = n$ and are bipartite for any even $n$.

Comment: This answer cleared up any confusion. I can't remember in what context this question came to my mind though unfortunately.

Comment: It's an interesting question in its own right. I've been trying to prove that if you exclude the cube graph, then the upper bound otherwise is $F_4 \leq n$ (that is, that you cannot have a bicubic planar graph with $n+1$ 4-sided faces and 1 $j$-sided face for $j > 4$). We already know that the bound of $n$ is achieved for arbitrarily large $n$.

Comment: I found a proof of the bound $F_4 \leq n$ for all bicubic planar graphs except the cube graph, modeled on [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/541692/59435). (It's pretty easy to prove if you assume the graph is 3-connected; it's harder with less connectivity because two faces can share two different (non-adjacent) edges.